# How can I pass form values invisibly into a popup?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup, data-sharing

I have a grid of records on my page, and each record has an edit button. Clicking the edit button opens a Magnific Popup, using ajax type, with an edit form for that row. I need to pass in the data for the current record so that I can pre-populate the form fields with the current data.

We were originally passing in fields through the URL - so the popup anchor would look something like this (with ColdFusion):

```
<cfoutput><a class="editRecord" href="editRecord.cfm?recordID=#recordID#&field1=#field1#&field2=#field2#<img src="../images/edit_icon.png" /></a></cfoutput>
```

And the code to invoke magnific popup:

```
$('.editRecord').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    preloader: false
});
```

But we don't want to expose the ID in the URL. Is there any way to pass in the field values without exposing them in the URL?

Comment: May be it will help you https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [Magnific Popup plugin documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html), you can find a section specific for the [AJAX type](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#ajax-type). According to it, you can add AJAX options by using the `ajax` and `settings` properties:

> ```
> ajax: {
>   settings: null, // Ajax settings object that will extend default one - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings
>   // For example:
>   // settings: {cache:false, async:false}
> ```

You could use that option to send the AJAX using the `POST` method instead of the `GET` method (default), that way not exposing the fields in the URL.

Now, instead of adding the parameters in the address, you could have them as `data-` attributes, and add them dynamically to the call using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

The HTML:

```
<cfoutput>
    <a class="editRecord" href="editRecord.cfm" data-recordid="RecID" data-field1="val1">
        <img src="../images/edit_icon.png" />
    </a>
</cfoutput>
```

And the JavaScript initialization:

```
$('.editRecord').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    preloader: false,
    ajax: {
        settings: {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                recordID: $(this).data("recordid"),
                field1: $(this).data("field1"),
                // similar with the rest of the fields
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

I tested that code locally... and it failed miserably. It's like `this` is not available inside the `magnificPopup()` function. I went around that issue by selecting the fields first and then applying the Magnific Popup plugin using the `each()` function like this:

```
$(".editRecord").each(function() {
    $(this).magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        preloader: false,
        ajax: {
            settings: {
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    recordID: $(this).data("recordid"),
                    field1: $(this).data("field1"),
                    // similar with the rest of the fields
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Maybe not the best solution, but it works in the tests I ran.

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for something like this but couldn't seem to find it in the docs. Will try implementing it. But then how do I access those data attributes from within the form code?

Comment: how do you access those data attributes from within the popup?

Comment: What do you mean? On the page, you can read the parameters from the POST (for example, I loaded a PHP file with AJAX and just had to do `$_POST["recordID"]` to get the value of recordID on my PHP code)

Comment: Ok, so in CF that probably means it would be in the FORM scope. I'll test it out. Thanks

Comment: From the URL scope. It does get sent to the form scope, but I had to change `method: "POST"` to `type: "POST"`. Still trying to figure out how to access the calling element from the code to avoid the "each" hack, but it works. Thanks!